# How does javascript look up a member of an object through its prototype chain?

Tags: javascript

When evaluating the value of 
`myObject.myMember`

My guess is that javascript will try to look up the "myMember" entry in:

```
    myObject
    myObject.constructor.prototype
    myObject.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype
    myObject.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype
    .......
```

until succeed.

The following code seems to validate my guess

```
var MyClass1=function(){
    this.key1="value1"; 
};
var myObject=new MyClass1();

MyClass1.prototype.key2="value2";

console.log(myObject.constructor.prototype.key2=="value2"); //true
console.log(myObject.key2=="value2"); //true   :)
```

But the following code proves my guess is wrong

```
var MyClass1=function(){
    this.key1="value1"; 
};

var MyClass2=function(){
    this.key2="value2"; 
};

var myObject=new MyClass1();

MyClass1.prototype=new MyClass2();
console.log(myObject.constructor.prototype.key2=="value2");//true
console.log(myObject.key2=="value2");// false! why?
```

What is the actual algorithm by which javascript looks up a member of an object through its prototype chain?

Comment: There's a difference between classes/prototypes and objects. In the second example you're assigning an object instance to a prototype. I'm very surprised something like that would work at all and not tear a hole in the space-time continuwuwuwuwuwum.

Comment: This line `MyClass1.prototype=new MyClass2();` omits the idea that you need the `myObject.prototype.constructor` object property to point to MyClass1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you called `MyClass1.prototype=new MyClass2();` *after* creating an instance of `MyClass1`.

```
var MyClass1=function(){
    this.key1="value1"; 
};

var MyClass2=function(){
    this.key2="value2"; 
};

MyClass1.prototype=new MyClass2();

var myObject=new MyClass1();

myObject.key1 === "value1";
myObject.key2 === "value2";
```

Let's inspect the operation `var myObject=new MyClass1()`

The `new` operator ( http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.2 ) calls the `[[Construct]]` internal method of `myClass1` (pseudo-code, of course.)

This is the skimmed version of what happens inside `[[Construct]]` ( http://es5.github.com/#x13.2.2 ) calls (obviously pseudo-code):

```
//fun in our operation is MyClass1
function Construct ( fun ) {
    //we create a fresh new object
    var obi = makeNewObject();

    //grab the prototype of MyClass1
    var proto = fun.prototype;
    //and set the actual prototype of obi to that prototype
    setPrototype( obi, proto );

    //and then returning the created and altered object, that will be myObject
    return obi;
 }
```

By "actual prototype", I mean not the `fun.prototype` you're used of seeing - that prototype looks forward, to instances we will create. The `[[Prototype]]` of an object is the properties inherited *to* it, it's its past.

That can be retrieved by using `Object.getPrototypeOf`, and in some implementations can be set using the non-standard `obj.__proto__`.

Okay, now that we've established how objects are created using `new`, why doesn't your example work?

Replacing `MyClass1.prototype` after you create `myObject` will break the link that was between the two. `MyClass1` has moved to the dark side, it has completely changed, a new object now replaces it, and `myObject` wants nothing to do with that.

Before the change, `myObject.__proto__ === MyClass1.prototype`, it holds a reference to the object `MyClass1.prototype`. Once you've changed the object `MyClass1.prototype`, `myObject.__proto__` will continue referencing that old object instead of the new one.

The answer is pretty much done. To rehash - The `[[Construct]]` function establishes a link between `MyClass1.prototype` and `myObject`. That link doesn't change when you replace `MyClass1.prototype`, so `myObject` will happily live with the object it was originally linked to.

In case you're still curious about how property fetching is done: http://es5.github.com/#x8.12.2 I warn you though, spec-language is tedious to read.

Answer (score 0):

This is because after creating myObject instance you "reprototype" MyClass1.
So this is how it works:

```
function BaseClass() {
   this.key1 = "value";
};

BaseClass.prototype.method1 = function()  { };

function SubClass() {
    this.key2 = "value";
}

SubClass.prototype = new BaseClass();
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;  //just to have classnames rendered correctly in webkit
SubClass.prototype.method2 = function()  { };

var instance = new SubClass();

console.log(instance instanceof BaseClass); //true
console.log(instance instanceof SubClass); //true
console.log("key1" in instance); //true
console.log(instance.hasOwnProperty(key1));// false
console.log(instance.hasOwnProperty(key2));// true
console.log("key2" in instance); //true;
console.log("method1" in instance); //true;
console.log("method2" in instance); //true;
```

Also following the prototypechain is best done with Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(...))